# Need library help for Arduino USB host shield

Tags: arduino-uno

Recently Purchased a "TOOGOO(R) T45 USB Host Shield" from Amazon. I attempted to use the "USB Host Shield Library" from Github, but It seems like it might not support this particular shield.

I would really like to learn how to use this shield to interact with my joystick but the only tutorial information I have found to help me with this is from Circuits@home and they seem to be using a specific shield in their development of the code library.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or Github library that can help me learn to work with this setup?

I'm using an Arduino Uno and a Thrustmaster USB joystick.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE*

I fixed the initial problem of accessing the HIDDESC report. I now have the report, but the formatting of the report is particularly hard to understand. Using the Circuits@home articles I'm a little lost on how to read the report data I was given. It does not seem to be formatted in the same way as the example. Can anyone help with interpreting my device report?

> Start
>   0000: 05 01 09 04 A1 01 09 01 A1 00 09 30 09 31 09 32
>   0010: 09 BB 15 80 25 7F 46 FF 00 66 00 00 66 00 00 75
>   0020: 08 95 04 81 02 C0 09 39 15 01 25 08 35 00 46 3B
>   0030: 01 65 14 75 04 95 01 81 02 05 09 19 01 29 04 15
>   0040: 00 25 01 75 01 95 04 81 02 95 08 81 01 05 08 09
>   0050: 43 15 00 26 FF 00 35 00 46 FF 00 75 08 95 04 91
>   0060: 82 55 00 65 00 55 00 65 00 55 00 C0
>   Usage Page Gen Desktop Ctrls(01)
>   Usage Game Pad
>   Collection Application
>   Usage Pointer
>   Collection Physical
>   Usage X
>   Usage Y
>   Usage Z
>   Usage Undef
>   Logical Min(80)
>   Logical Max(7F)
>   Physical Max(FF00)
>   Unit(0000)
>   Unit(0000)
>   Report Size(08)
>   Report Count(04)
>   Input(00000010)
>   End Collection
>   Usage Hat Switch
>   Logical Min(01)
>   Logical Max(08)
>   Physical Min(00)
>   Physical Max(3B01)
>   Unit(14)
>   Report Size(04)
>   Report Count(01)
>   Input(00000010)
>   Usage Page Button(09)
>   Usage Min(01)
>   Usage Max(04)
>   Logical Min(00)
>   Logical Max(01)
>   Report Size(01)
>   Report Count(04)
>   Input(00000010)
>   Report Count(08)
>   Input(00000001)
>   Usage Page LEDs(08)
>   Usage Slow Blk On Time
>   Logical Min(00)
>   Logical Max(FF00)
>   Physical Min(00)
>   Physical Max(FF00)
>   Report Size(08)
>   Report Count(04)
>   Output(10000010)
>   Unit Exp(00)
>   Unit(00)
>   Unit Exp(00)
>   Unit(00)
>   Unit Exp(00)
>   End Collection Game Pad Pointer X Y Z Undef(00)(00)(7F)(00)
>   Hat Switch(00)
>   Btn0001
>   (00) Btn0002
>   (00) Btn0003
>   (00) Btn0004
>   (00)
>   (00)(00)(00)(00)(00)(00)(00)(00)
>   Slow Blk On Time

Comment: I think you will need to get the library for your shield.

Comment: Identify the chip on your shield, and identify the chip on the shields that are supported.  Typically these fly-by-night boards are just clones of better supported ones, but you could have anything including an inert paperweight.  Worth considering that a host shield on an Arduino is generally a bad idea to begin with; if you want to host a USB peripheral, use a processor that can do so natively - it will be both cheaper and less roundabout.  Also realize that only trivial well documented USB peripherals make sense for MCUs; for more complex things you probably want an embedded Linux system.

Comment: @code Gorilla, where would I get the library for my shield?

Comment: @ChrisStratton the chip is a max 3421EE 1637. It seems to work fine, and be designed well enough, but thanks for the input.

Comment: @B.Guisgand - The library, if it exists, will be somewhere on the internet, I know that isn't helpful but what else can I say.  I think you might have misunderstood Chris's point.  Put bluntly you well down S creek with no paddle and he was handing you an outboard motor.

Comment: @CodeGorilla lol. Yeah I figured as much. I'm trying my best with this project, but can't drop $66 just for joystick functionality, might just have to scratch that portion of the project if I can't buy a cheaper shield option. Honestly all i need is the ability to plug a cheap joystick in and get it to increase or decrease the digits on a 4 digit 7 segment display.

Comment: So use a cheap plain joystick directly wired to the Arduino.

Comment: @ChrisStratton and where would i get one, been looking everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The photos on Amazon show a clone of the circuit@home board so the same library should work. You may be running into the problem mentioned in the following page.

https://esp8266-notes.blogspot.com/2017/08/defective-arduino-usb-host-shield-boards.html